# qemu: i specify 2 ide drives, but a third cdrom magically appear

Tags: qemu

Simple question:

I specify 2 ide drives, one is cdrom, other is hard disk

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2048 -drive file=debian-10.0.0.iso,if=ide,index=1,media=cdrom -drive file=disk.img,if=ide,index=0,media=disk -boot d --enable-kvm -device pcnet,netdev=network0,mac=****** -netdev tap,id=network0,ifname=tap1,script=no,downscript=no
```

the system run ok, but when I open a shell I see three block devices

one is sda, is the hard disk, is ok
two is sr0 and is the cdrom, is ok
third is sr1 and is recognized as cdrom without medium!
The question is: where the sr1 came from?
I have tried Debian and Slackware cd, and both report the sr1 drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried Debian and CentOS with `-drive file=debian.iso,if=ide,index=1,media=cdrom` and all add an extra `srX` device. It seems all my VMs have `/dev/sr0` by default and the command adds an extra device.

This seems normal for most Linux distributions. Most systems have at least one `/dev/sr0` by default and QEMU will add devices if you specify them.

I can give you an other example with floppy disks ...

```
[~] ls /dev/fd*
3  0  1  2

[root@centos ~]# ls /dev/fd*
0 1 2 3

root@debian:~# ls /dev/fd*
/dev/fd0

/dev/fd:
0 1 2 3
```

Not sure any one will use nor have any floppy drive. But still those devices exists.

Answer (score 1):

The cd drive is a part of qemu; you can't get rid of it.